# Create a selectable square button, that open with double click in Xcode (Cocoa)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, focus, nsbutton

How to create a Square Button, that once clicked on once it gets selected (focus ring) and once its clicked on twice it performs an action.

Is it possible to do that in XIB file?

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate(or some other class):

```
@property BOOL alreadyClickedButton;
```

Then initialize the property:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [self setAlreadyClickedButton:NO];

}
```

Then in an action:

```
-(IBAction)onclickButton:(id)sender {
    if ([self alreadyClickedButton] ) {
        NSLog(@"Do something...");
        [self setAlreadyClickedButton:NO]; //Reset the button to initial state?
    }
    else {
        [[self window] makeFirstResponder:sender];
        [self setAlreadyClickedButton:YES];
    }
}
```

Every two clicks of that button, you will see the message.